Vertex coloring of the Rado graph
Is there a reference for the following fact about the Rado graph (the random countable graph) which came up in an answer to this question?

If the vertices of the Rado graph $G=(V,E)$ are colored with finitely many colors, say $V=C_1\cup\cdots\cup C_n$, then for some color $i\in[n]$ there is a subset $X$ of $C_i$ which is a maximal clique of $G$.

